# What is the point of Return False in a python program?

Tags: python, function

Okay, so I was tasked by a teacher with some practice questions and one of them, my first step is to check if a number is prime. I didn't really know how so I resorted to chatGPT to see how it would do it and it had something in the code like this:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
```

what does the return thing do. Why not just end program if it's false or ask the user to enter a new number. I'm semi-new at this btw, so a basic answer would be greatly appreciated

tried understanding chatGPT's explanations and other stack overflow posts

Comment: The function is supposed to return a value that indicates whether the argument is prime. It returns `True` when it is, and `False` when it isn't.

Comment: your function can be written as `return not n <= 1`   or also `return n > 1`. so you return a value always and you actually don't need an explicit conditional in this case.

Comment: The algorithm for testing if a number is prime only works for numbers higher than 1, so it returns False immediately so it doesn't go through the rest of the code.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki This is obviously just part of the function -- the rest of it goes through the prime testing algorithm.

Comment: ah, yes, missed the point. I didn;t even read the function name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prime number is defined by:
A prime number is a whole number **greater than 1** whose only factors are 1 and itself. A factor is a whole number that can be divided evenly into another number. The first few prime numbers are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 and 29. Numbers that have more than two factors are called composite numbers.

If the number itself is less than 1, by definition it is not prime.

What is a return statement?:
"A return statement is used to end the execution of the function call and “returns” the result (value of the expression following the return keyword) to the caller. The statements after the return statements are not executed. If the return statement is without any expression, then the special value None is returned."

In basic English, this means that, a function - aka a small chunk of code that can be reused - returns a value after it is finished running the code.

The return false in the example you provided is to indicate that the number is not prime (because it can not be prime if it's less than 1)

If a prime number is detected, then the function would return true.

As to your questions:
Why not end the program if it's false? -> It's possible you could do other things with your program even after determining if a number is prime or not, in real world situations, a program might be used to determine if a number is prime & then go on to doing other tasks.

Why not ask the user to enter a new number? -> It's possible that you might want to use this function on existing data & not have any new data inputs.   (example: a file of numbers that never changes)

[https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/prime-number#:~:text=A%20prime%20number%20is%20a,factors%20are%20called%20composite%20numbers](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/prime-number#:%7E:text=A%20prime%20number%20is%20a,factors%20are%20called%20composite%20numbers).

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/

Comment: i think i get it? Please correct me if i'm wrong but I got that the return statement stops a called funtion and returns the end value to the user. Is it like 'break' in a loop but it also outputs the result?

Comment: Yes the return statement does indeed stop the called function and returns the end value :)

Whether or not it is output, depends on whether a print() statement is called

Comment: It is kind of similar to break except that return will exit the function whereas break will exit the loop

Comment: thank you so much. I've had a hard time wrapping this stuff around my head. Appreciate it

Comment: You're so welcome!